# Site switcher on this site shows wrong icons

Tags: bug

The site switcher on this site shows incorrect icons for this site as well as the sites in "your communities". Other sites in "more Stack Exchange communities" show the correct icons:

[image: Wrong icons on this site]

The issue seems to be specific to this site. On other sites, the icons render fine:

[image: Correct icons on another site]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Last time this happened and was reported on MSE, it was said to ['blame caching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315472/369802). As I'm not seeing the same icons as you, I think this may be the case here too.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell It could be a CDN issue. I'll see how it looks from a different VPN address

Comment: It takes a while for the sprites to get added to the sprites list. It usually clears itself up pretty quickly.

Comment: Looks fine to me now?